# Bluetooth module android & ios appcelerator

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, titanium, appcelerator

I need a module that works both on Android and iOS devices. I tried to use `BLUETOOTH LE MODULE` but it didn't work on iOS devices with SDK 6.0.4 and as a matter of fact it did work with SDK < 5.5.1.

How can I connect a bluetooth device to Android and iOS devices with Appcelerator with SDK 6.0.4?

Comment: Could you please show us what you have tried so far, such that we can help you

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/hansemannn/titanium-bluetooth was recommended to me. I have yet to implement it tho... next week :)

Comment: i've also used this module but it didn't work very well and it didn't show a list of available peripheral

Comment: Have you tried looking at https://github.com/AppWerft/Ti.A2DP or https://github.com/whilu/LMBluetoothSdk. That may give some clues.

Comment: github.com/whilu/LMBluetoothSdk how can I include this sdk in titanium app with sdk 6.0.4.GA?